# 5 node Riak setup: 100 ops/sec throughput. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, erlang, riak

Here is my setup of Riak 1.1.4

- 5 Nodes
- ami-a29943cb (EC2 AMI)
- m1.large (7.5GB Ram, 4 EC2 compute instances)
- EBS storage
- LevelDB backend
- Python Client with Protobuf (on a separate machine)

I tried running basho benchmark on the setup and it showed 100 ops/sec throughput.

After talking to people or Riak IRC, I realized that upwards of 1.5K ops/sec is what I should be getting.

Could anyone help me in figuring out what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,
Yousuf

Comment: Relevant configuration options/excerpts ?
Nothing killing the machines if you check with `top` & `iostat` etc ?

Comment: Nothing out of the ordinary that I can see via top and iostat

Comment: Not sure if EBS has something to do with it. Have you tried levelDB on the local filesystem?

Comment: Yes I did. It didnt help

Comment: Are all the nodes in the same region? What are your N/R/W parameters set to? Which OS?

Comment: Where did you run basho benchmark from? Do you have any resource monitoring in place? It's possible that the true bottleneck is the system running the test (or transport to the cluster) but you will need to measure to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

EBS is pretty slow. Have you tried either RAID'ing your EBS volumes, or running ephemeral?

http://lists.basho.com/pipermail/riak-users_lists.basho.com/2011-April/003712.html